# Function will not read full input

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, while-loop, ifstream

I call a function like so `getseconddata (list2,n)`

input file reads

```
45 P 19
11 S 56
45 S F
30 P F
```

and the function code reads

```
void getseconddata(employeetype list2[], int n)
{
ifstream infile2;
  string filename;
  int id, changenum;
  char stat, changealpha;
cout<<"Enter name of second data file"<<endl;
  cin>>filename;
  infile2.open(filename.c_str());
  infile2>>id;
  while (getline(infile2))
    {
infile2>>stat;
      if (stat=='S')
        {
        infile2>>changealpha;
        }
      else if (stat=='P')
        {
    infile2>>changenum;
        }
      infile2>>id;
    }
  infile2.close();
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
  cout<<id<<stat<<changealpha<<changenum<<endl;
}
}
```

output reads

```
45 P 19
45 P 19
45 P 19
45 P 19
```

I have tried rewriting the code and looking up basic functions and eof online. help

Answer (score 0):

**First:** Your use of `getline` is incorrect and your code should **not** compile.

```
while(getline(infile2)) { ... }
```

`infile2` is an `ifstream`. There is no signature of `getline` that takes an `ifstream&`. There is a signature that takes an `ifstream` and a `string`, use like so:

```
stringstream buffer;
while(getline(infile2, line)) {
    buffer << line;
    buffer >> id >> stat;
    // ...
    buffer.clear() // to reset for next iteration
}
```

**Second:** The output you're receiving is the output your `for` loop dictates.

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    cout << id << stat << changealpha << changenum << endl;
}
```

This `for` loop, if your use of `getline` was correct, is going to output `30 P F`, the data from the last line, `n` times. It's not going to output `n` different indexes of `list2`. The reason being is that your variables are reset on every iteration of the `while` loop, and since your `for` loop is run after your `while` loop it only makes since that the last line be output.

**Third:** Your `if-else-if` conditional dictates something other than your input file.

```
if(stat == 'S') {
    infile2 >> changealpha; // 'changealpha' is a 'char'
} else if(stat == 'P') {
    infile2 >> changenum;   // 'changenum' is an 'int'
}
```

The above logic does not fit the format of your input file:

```
45 P 19 // 'stat' is P suggests 'int'  - correct
11 S 56 // 'stat' is S suggests 'char' - ??? - there are 3 chars after S (' ', '5', '6')?
45 S F  // 'stat' is S suggests 'char' - correct
30 P F  // 'stat' is P suggests 'int'  - ??? - do you want the ASCII char code of 'F'?
```